# how do I get plus sign in rectangle in css?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve this plus sign in rectangle in red

[image]

I tried it using css

```html
<p align="left">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
  adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
  incididunt 
  <span style="color:red; margin-left:47px; border: 1px solid red;">
    +
  </span>
</p>
```

Its showing like below:

[image]

I am not able to understand why there is space at top and bottom of the plus sign.

How can I get that plus sign in proper rectangle?

Comment: Inspect the element in your Element Inspector and see what CSS impacts the element.

Comment: Why not simply `<span style="color: red;" >&#x229E;</span>`?

Comment: @ Mave: I tried by giving padding, width, height but that space not getting removed. Also tried by checking line-height of <p> tag.

Comment: @kiran  i hope this will help you most : https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: @ MATH.h: I have already referred and tried that. thanks.

Comment: If you really want to understand the reason, then see my answer posted below, if you want to just get away with any random solution, there are other answers too below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qtjmjmgz/4/)**

CSS:

```
p:after{
    content:"+";
    margin:0 0 0 47px !important;
    color:red;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height:8px;
    width:8px;
    line-height:8px;    
    display: inline-block;
    font-size:12px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

HTML:

```
<p align="left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
span.plus {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 9px;
  height: 9px;
  width: 9px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="plus">+
  </span>
```

Comment: Bonus points if you make it into a pseudo element on the paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<span class="plus">+</span>
```

CSS:

```
.plus
{
display:inline-block;
width:auto;
height:auto;
line-height:10px;
padding:1px;
border:1px solid red;
color:red;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Actually in HTML Document each line has particular line height, same is the case here the extra height you see here is actually the minimum line height.

You need to add a `line-height` to the `span` therefore overidding the line height in your `p`

For Example:

```
line-height:10px;
```

Check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e6ey7r47/)

Comment: Appologies, the wording and demo were confusing. I thought you were saying you needed to remove the line height, because that was what your demo did! I've edited your answer to make it more clear, edit as appropriate. I don't really get why you've commented out the fix in your fiddle? Why comment out the most important bit? Also you should really add the p as the context is important.

Comment: comment was just so that it would be more easy to understand, that what good happens after you take them off. Thanks by the way, would be much clear next time

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without (a lot of) CSS, by simply using a `⊞` character:

```html
<p align="left">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
  adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
  incididunt 
  <span style="color: red; margin-left: 47px;" >&#x229E;</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

HTML:

```
<p> some content</p>
```

CSS:

```
p:after{
  content:"+";
  margin:0 0 0 47px !important;
  color:red;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height:8px;
  width:8px;
  line-height:8px;    
  display: inline-block;
  font-size:12px;
  vertical-align:middle;
```

}